# Opencv feature matching without drawing

Tags: python, opencv

I have a large image with pics of digits on it. And I have many templates of these digits at small pictures.

So, I want to comparing big image with my templates, for determining identical images - and getting right numbers.

TEMPLATE MATCHING doesn't work in my case, because little digits on large image can be rotated or have an disnormal prospect. Template matching doesn't see a difference between 6 and 9 for example, but also it think that 6 and 6 are different images when they are angled.

FEATURE MATCHING is better way, I think, but in this example I only can drawing similarity at output image, I don't need this, I want to get score or ratio: where number is bigger - there is right template.

Sorry for bad explanation.

I tried to add a pictures, but couldn't (indents are wrong, don't know why)

```
img1 = cv2.imread('large.png',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('20.png',0)
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:10],None, flags=2)
cv2.imshow('s',img3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: the information you need is in the "matches" variable. Read the docs and try to understand the content and its meaning.

Comment: If I print the "matches" > [<DMatch 000000CD4B93F750>, <DMatch 000000CD4B93F8F0>... What else I can do with it data? I didn't find info about this at docs yet.

Comment: you could look at the drawMatches code (it is open source!) how they use the values. But probably there is sample code somewhere in the internet.

Comment: have a look at the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690265/matching-features-with-orb-python-opencv how you can iterate over the matches and what the values represent. Looks like it is copied from the docs.